# calculating average numbers from a dictionary of lists, python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum, average

I my code I have a dictionary which has two lists combined with zip() function

```
self.dict = OrderedDict(zip(self.name,self.unit))
```

The lists are given as arguments... `var=class([[1,2,4,7],["y","y","t"],[11.1,12.3,6]],name=["num1","letter","num2"])`

In one point there should be a function which checks if the items in the each brackets has numbers only. for example `int=[1,2,3]`
if that's true the program calculates the average for each number only list. And prints out the values as  `num1 = 3.5 num2 = 9.8` (as a table):

```
num1   num2
 3.5    9.8
```

First I make a new list using this:

```
for i in range(len(self.unit)):
                    if  all(isinstance(item, (int,float)) for item in self.unit[i]):
                        self.new_l.append(self.unit[i])
```

After that I (in another function) create a new list called `self.sum_l` in which put in the average of each number list in a new list of lists (In this example i get two averages).

```
self.sum_l.append([sum(self.new_1[i])/float(len(self.new_1[i]))])
```

After that I make a new dictionary which uses the `self.name` and the `self.sum_1` lists

```
 self.nov_slovar = OrderedDict(zip(self.ime, self.seznam_vsot))
```

Which works fine, but the PROBLEM I'm facing is... when I create a new dictionary the code takes as much elements out of list `name` when forming a new dictionary, as there are lists in the `self.sum_1` list. But the thing is, it takes the first two (in my case). And that makes the output absolutely incorrect:

```
num1   letter
 4.6    9.8
```

So my question is, what should I do to prevent that from happening. I've tried many things. Even trying to calculate the sum of values in a dictionary, but I'm getting errors

Comment: I've just lost you sorry, what's `4.6`? `(1+2+4+7)/4 = 3.5` is it the expected result or the error you get?

Comment: It was an example, I calculated by head (wrongly:P). That's not the point. the point is, i want to calculate the average of lists (each by each) that contain only float or integer (or both).
My method has problems displaying the correct name.

Comment: How much code is it? Can you make a self-contained example that show the problem, so that we see the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from __future__ import division

self.nov_slovar = {}
for key, value in self.dict.iteritems():
    try:
        self.nov_slovar[key] = sum(value)/len(value)
    except TypeError:  # can't sum non-numbers; skip those
        pass
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but when use this:
`row = zip(*([key]+map(str,value) for key,value in (self.nov_slovar.iteritems())))`

i get a **TypeError: zip() argument after * must be a sequence, not generator**

Comment: Not sure why you want it that way, but anyway :-). My guess is you're using Python 3, and `map` returns a generator, not a sequence. That's easily solved by doing `zip(*([key]+list(map(str, value)) ...`: using `list()` will turn the generator output into a list.

Comment: if I do this:
`rows= zip(*((key,value).....`

it creats a tuple which is the output I want, but if I want to print it nicely, just the elements by using 

`"\n".join("\t ".join (row) for row in rows)`
i get **TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found**

Comment: How come is `self.nov_slovar[<key>]` an iterable for you? It's an average, that is, a single number. Thus, you shouldn't be able to use `map(str, value)`, since `value` is a `float` (or `int`).

Answer (score 1):

It very long question for something quite simple, I'm not sure I got your question correctly, but this might demonstrate a few things that might help...

```
import numbers

a = {"title": "num1", "values": [1,2,3,4,5]}
b = {"title": "letter", "values": [1,'b',3,4,5]}

def print_avg(r):
    if all(isinstance(x, numbers.Number) for x in r["values"]):
        print a["title"],":", sum(r["values"])/float(len(r["values"]))

print_avg(a)
>> num1 : 3.0
print_avg(b):
>>
```